# Laravel 4 validation says column not found

Tags: php, database, validation, laravel-4

This is my first time using Laravel 4. I am sending some input. There is an email in the input. I am trying to check whether that already exists or not. If it does than it should send some error. But it is saying there is no such column in my table.

Here is my code:

```
$rules = array(
        'email' => array('required', 'email', 'unique:users, user_email'),
        'password' => array('required', 'min:7', 'unique:users, user_password')
    );
 $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
  if($validation->fails())
{
   $messages = $validation->messages();

    dd($messages);
}
```

My table name is users and column name is user_email and user_password. The name of the input field is email.

Comment: I still don't have much experience with L4, though have you considered erasing that space between the comma, and `user_email`/`user_password`?  The documentation I'm reading specifies no such space.

Comment: @Daedalus, let me check.

Comment: Another note:  If you're developing a typical application and are properly hashing your passwords, you should've require passwords to be unique in your database.  This is not only not necessary, but a small security issue.  While registering myself on your site, if I get a message back saying the password I tried was not unique in your database, this lets me know that *some* user in your database has that password.  Then considering you're just using emails as usernames, I could easily just try that password on a collection of existing emails based on your password reset functionality.

Comment: @SajanParikh, thanks a lot. It never occured to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the documentation for [validation rules](http://four.laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique), I do not see any spacing between column names, and the column info.  It may be that spaces are not stripped from the data, and this would probably be the cause of your error.  Remove the spacing issues, and it should work: `unique:users,user_email,etc`.

(Note, this is an expanded answer based off of my comment, which solved the user's problem).